# Mongoose: update one document out of a bunch

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have the following code which nearly works. It will check if a status for a domain is already set, if not, it will push a new status. If there already is one, it will update it, unless there's multiple statuses for different domains stored, in which case it will replace all of the other documents for the other domains and not just the one entry for the specific domain.

```
      if (Boolean(checkStat) === true) {
        await userModel.findByIdAndUpdate(
          {
            _id: ctx.userId,
            domain: args.domain,
          },
          {
            ["preferences.domain.status"]: {
              domain: args.domain,
              status: args.status,
            },
          },

        );
        return {
          message:
            "sucessfully updated status of " +
            args.domain +
            " to " +
            args.status,
        };
      } else {
        await userModel.findByIdAndUpdate(
          ctx.userId,
          {
            $push: {
              ["preferences.domain.status"]: {
                domain: args.domain,
                status: args.status,
              },
            },
          },
          {
            upsert: true,
            new: true,
          }
        );
        return {
          message:
            "sucessfully set status of " + args.domain + " to " + args.status,
        };
      }
```

```
preferences:
  domain:
    labels:
    status:
      0:
        domain: "x.wtf"
        status: "online"
        _id: "Jz-ttsjEXKBSVxAN91CzD"
      1:
        domain: "a.lol"
        status: "online"
        _id: "Jz-ttsjEXKBSVxAN91CzD"
```

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  preferences: {
    domain: {
      status: [
        {
          _id: {
            type: String,
            default: () => nanoid(),
          },
          domain: String,
          status: String,
        },
      ],
      labels: [
        {
          _id: {
            type: String,
            default: () => nanoid(),
          },
          domain: String,
          label: String,
        },
      ],
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: Can you show your model?

Comment: So where's `domain` field in `userModel.findByIdAndUpdate({ _id: ctx.userId, domain: args.domain}...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [$](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) operator and `findOneAndUpdate` instead of `findByIdAndUpdate` to do that:

```
await userModel.findOneAndUpdate(
  {
    _id: ctx.userId,
    "preferences.domain.status.domain": args.domain,
  },
  {
    "preferences.domain.status.$.status": args.status,
  }
);
```

Comment: With `findByIdAndUpdate`, the first parameter should be an id, not an object like `findOneAndUpdate`